# Mpdf working on firefox but cant be loaded on chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-chrome, pdf, mpdf

I try creating to preview pdf function. Its running well on firefox, but when i run with google chrome the pdf cannot be loaded.

There is my php header code :

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600000);
    ini_set('memory_limit','-1');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
    $nama_dokumen='analispdf.pdf'; 
    define('_MPDF_PATH','mpdf60/'); 
    include(_MPDF_PATH . "mpdf.php"); 
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', 10.5, 'arial'); 
    $mpdf->AddPage('L');
    ob_start();
```

Then there was some html code, after html code i have php code like :

```
<?php

    $html = ob_get_contents(); 
    $stylesheet = file_get_contents (base_url().'assets/css/mpdfstyletables.css' );
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1); 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
    $mpdf->Output();
    exit;
```

i was searching on several website, but still didnt get solution.
Can anyone please guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched? More importantly, exactly what error do you get in chrome that you don't get in Firefox? Is the PDF being generated but it's corrupt? Is the download ending at 0 bytes? Have you tried making the browser download the file instead of displaying inline? Etc?

Comment: There was no error, on firefox the pdf was succesfully generated and can be previewed. But on chrome still no error, there was only a message the pdf cant be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this code

```
$html = ob_get_contents();
```

because it returns no view. you need to put a layout or output you desire to your `$html` varible before you pass it to `$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);` function.

Comment: "_Then there was some html code, after html code i have php code like :_"

i have some html code before `$html = ob_get_contents();`
its was proven on firefox, code of html works well and there was an output.